# ember-cli: ember test error global modules not found

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Using ember-cli 0.1.15 'ember test' giving error trying to use moment.
The helper below loads fine in the browser, but the test fails trying to find moment.js:

```
Could not find module app/helpers/bower_components/moment/moment
```

### App Helper

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from './bower_components/moment/moment';
export function formattedDate(date, format) {
  return moment(date).format(format);
}
export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(formattedDate);
```

### Test

```
import {
  formattedDate
} from '../../../helpers/formatted-date';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

module('FormattedDateHelper');

test('Unit FormattedDate', function(assert) {
  var Xmas95 = new Date('December 25, 1995 11:15:30');
  var result = formattedDate(Xmas95,'MMMM Do, YYYY [at] h:mm a');
  assert.ok(result === 'December 25th, 1995 at 11:15 am', 'boom:  '.concat(result));
});
```

### Brocfile.js

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp();

app.import('bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js');
module.exports = app.toTree();
```

### Full Error Message

not ok 21 PhantomJS 1.9 - TestLoader Failures: market/tests/unit/helpers/formatted-date-test: could not be loaded
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            Died on test #1     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2535
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5297
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:31
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:40
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5301: Could not find module market/helpers/bower_components/moment/moment
        Log: >
    ...

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add "moment" to the "predef" section of my .jshintrc files like follows:
    "predef": [
      "document",
      "window",
      "-Promise",
      "moment"
    ],